# Exporting data from different notebooks to a common file

Tags: export, import, notebooks, contexts

I am doing some calculations from different notebooks. I need to export the results from all those notebooks in columns of the same file, like

> a1 b1 c1
>   a2 b2 c2
>   a3 b3 c3
>   .  .  .

where a, b and c are the different notebooks.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TYZEC.png

Comment: It is not clear what you asking here. Do you want the data in the external file for use outside _Mathematica_? Or do you think you need the external as a conduit between the three notebooks?

Answer (score 3):

What belisarius is trying to say in his comment is that variables in one notebook are normally accessible in another without problems.

If you happen to have set your notebooks to have unique contexts like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

then you can obtain the qualified name for the variables in two ways:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(to be executed in the notebook where the variable is defined).

You then use the full names in `Export` to export the results to an external file.

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear. I need to print all my results in the same .dat. However, this results are obtained from different Mathematica notebooks. I want to export all the results in columns, such that I can differentiate them more easily. Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: @JoseJAlonso You're still rather confusing. Is your problem exporting in columns or accessing data in different notebooks? An answer to the latter is provided above and an answer to the former can be found in the `Export` documentation ([here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Table.html)). There are also many questions on exporting on this site, that can be easily found without much effort.

Comment: You were right, I have already solve the problem, thanks...